# Bad F# code performance on simple loop compared to C# - Why?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, f#

I was wondering why I get such disparate results between apparently equal algorithms in C# and F#.

F# code variants:

```ml
open System
{ 1I..(bigint (Int32.MaxValue / 100)) } |> Seq.sum

let mutable sum = 0I
for i in 1I..(bigint (Int32.MaxValue / 100)) do
    sum <- sum + i
sum

let sum = ref 0I
for i in 1I..(bigint (Int32.MaxValue / 100)) do
    sum := !sum + i
sum
```

Full F# code (4s):

```ml
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let sw = new Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    printfn "%A" ({ 1I..(bigint (Int32.MaxValue / 100)) } |> Seq.sum)
    sw.Stop()
    printfn "took %A" sw.Elapsed
    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

Full C# code (22s):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    BigInteger sum = new BigInteger(0);
    BigInteger max = new BigInteger(Int32.MaxValue / 100);
    Console.WriteLine(max);
    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger(1); i <= max; ++i)
    {
        sum += i;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The F# code takes more than 22s on any of its variants (I assumed different implementations would yield different running times but that doesn't seem to be the case). On the other hand, the C# code seems to be way faster. Both yield the same final sum result, so I guess the algorithms are equivalent. I double checked and the F# code seems to be compiled with the `--optimize+` flag.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try using a `to` `for` loop rather than `in`.

Comment: @ildjarn - for loops with `to` require `int` types but here we use a `BigInteger` so this won't work.

Comment: @JohnPalmer : Ah, apologies, I didn't realize that (I literally have never used `for` in F# :-P).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Converting the F# code from

```ml
{ 1I..(bigint (Int32.MaxValue / 100)) } |> Seq.sum;;
Real: 00:00:14.014, CPU: 00:00:14.196, GC gen0: 1743, gen1: 0
```

to

```ml
let mutable t = 1I
let mutable res = 0I
let max = bigint (Int32.MaxValue / 100)
while t < max do             
    res <- res + t
    t <- t + 1I;;
Real: 00:00:05.379, CPU: 00:00:05.450, GC gen0: 748, gen1: 0
```

Approxiamately triples the speed, and is also closer to the original C# code.

The most likely reason is that both `{...}` and `for i in ...` create a dummy `seq`.  By removing this, you avoid the `seq` overhead.

**EDIT**

For some reason F# is generating a ridiculous amount of IL for this code, and is using a really weird comparison.

If we explicitly force the comparison, the speed doubles (which is a little ridiculous)

This code gets pretty much exactly the same speed as the C# for me (on mono).

```ml
let mutable t = 1I
let mutable res = 0I
let max = (bigint (Int32.MaxValue / 100));;
while System.Numerics.BigInteger.op_GreaterThan(max,t) do             
     res <- res + t;t<-System.Numerics.BigInteger.op_Increment(t) 
printfn "%A" res
```

but is unnecersarrily verbose.

I will probably file a compiler bug about this.

Comment: That's strange, as stated in the OP all the 3 F# variants yield exactly the same speed here. Or maybe I'm in a great need of sleep. I'll run them again..

Comment: @devouredelysium - I am proposing a new alternative which is significantly faster - all your versions took about 15s on my computer.

Comment: Your algorithm takes 8.8s here. It's indeed better, but even so I'd expect it to match the C# version :( That's just too slow.

Comment: @devouredelysium - what is your C# time?

Comment: @devouredelysium - see update I got the F# about 2x faster than before.

Comment: The compiler is generating a call to [`HashCompare.GenericLessOrEqualIntrinsic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee789259.aspx) instead of the type-specific operator (`BigInteger.op_LessThanOrEqual`), and additional type annotations don't help. That is, to say the least, unexpected.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: Did you send this to fsbugs? Any response?

Comment: @Daniel - Since I was using the open source version I filed an issue here https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/201

Answer (score 2):

This is the fastest/shortest functional version I could come up with - it cheats a little by using a sequence of ints. It's roughly as fast as John Palmer's version on Mono.

```
{1..(System.Int32.MaxValue/100)} |> Seq.sumBy (fun x -> bigint(x)) |> printfn "%A"
```

I also made a functional version of what John Palmer did with one exception in that it includes the max value in the sum to match the above sequence based version:

```
let rec sum (cnt:bigint) (acc:bigint) (max:bigint) =
    if bigint.op_LessThanOrEqual(cnt,max) then
        sum (bigint.op_Increment(cnt)) (acc+cnt) max
    else
        acc

sum 1I 0I (bigint (System.Int32.MaxValue / 100)) |> printfn "%A"
```